# Android: How to switch from Fragment to Main Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My MainActivity is the Google Maps Activity and I have 2 fragments called "LoginForm" and "appSettings". I can switch from the MainActivity to the 2 fragments, but I can't switch back to MainActivity. I have tried fragment.addToBackStack() but it doesn't do anything. Any idea? Here is the code from the Navigation Drawer.

```
public void selectedDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem){

    Class fragmentClass = null;
    FrameLayout frameLayoutMap = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_container_login);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    // For every new Fragment, add in Switch statement.
    switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.nav_geomap:
            fragmentClass = MapsActivity.class;
            break;

        case R.id.nav_login:
            Log.d(TAG, "Accessed fragment: menuItem nav_login");
            //frameLayoutMap.removeAllViews();
            fragmentClass = LoginForm.class;
            break;

        case R.id.nav_settings:
            Log.d(TAG, "Accessed fragment: menuItem nav_settings");
            // frameLayoutMap.removeAllViews();
            fragmentClass = appSettings.class;
            break;

    }
    try
    {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, fragment).commit();

    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();


}
```

Comment: can you please describe more a attache screenshot of that app

Comment: @JayDwivedi [Here is a GIF of my app](https://i.imgur.com/DvJ39Tn.gifv)

Comment: have you tried    "getActivity().onBackPressed();"

Comment: Wat is R.id.map? Why did you replace with map instead of frame_container?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public void addPage(Fragment fragment) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.content_main, fragment);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }

public void forwardPage(final Fragment fragment) {

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
```